# Can a ship with disabled abilities jump?

Tags: sins-of-a-solar-empire-rebellion

There is a new advent capital ship that can disable a ship's abilities, will this prevent them from being able to jump out of a sector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rest of the SoaSE games, a ship with abilities disabled can still jump. They may have changed this in Rebellion, but I doubt it. You might want to check that the ability-disabling move doesn't also prevent jumping, as the Dunov Battlecruiser's EMP ability does.

Comment: hmm... so advent still doesn't have a good jump inhibitor :(

Comment: I find blowing them up to be a pretty good jump inhibitor ;)

Comment: only if you can get them before they jump out :P